# Fancybox conflict?

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I'm trying to implement a Fancybox email form to a website but I can't get it to work on the live site.

It works fine when I use the code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/svsdx/

However, I think there may be a conflict with some of the code in the . I've tried removing some elements but I can't find what's causing it. No doubt I'm being a complete idiot, but can anyone spot a possible issue here?

```
<head>  

<!--Favicon-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> 

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<!-- /CSS -->

<!-- Fonts --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/hte5kvm.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
<!-- /Fonts -->

<!-- Ticker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://labs.ft.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/jquery.ticker.js"></script>
<!-- /Ticker -->

<!-- FancyBox -->   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
<!-- /FancyBox -->

<!-- JS -->
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
<!-- /JS -->

 <!--Analytics-->
 <script type="text/javascript">

   var _gaq = _gaq || [];
   _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

   (function() {
     var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
     ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
   })();

 </script>     

  </head>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you see in console.. try chrome inspect element or firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Typekit scripts link. If TypeKit script is the problem, try using their Advanced Embed code instead: http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/649336-embed-code